# alternative to file_get_contents for reading the JSON data from POST URL?

Tags: php, json

I have the POST URL as "**http://domain/mycontroller/function/info.json**" , How to read the "`info.json`" , I am using `file_get_contents("php://input")` but is there any alternative to read `JSON` data or "`info.json`".

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Answer (score 0):

if its on local machine you can use

```
 fopen 
 fclose
```

http://php.net/manual/bg/function.fopen.php

if its on remote machine you can use

```
 curl
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: It's also possible to use ```fopen()``` with remote files.

Answer (score 0):

sped of the

you can use the fopen or curl

the sped

```
curl>>>fopen>file_get_contents
```